# $\{A_\alpha\}$ closed, locally finite, $f\restriction_{A_\alpha}$ continuous; show $f$ continuous

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\{ A_\alpha \}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$; let $X=\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha$. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$; suppose that $f\restriction_{A_\alpha}$, is continuous for each $\alpha$. Show that if $\{ A_\alpha \}$ is locally finite and each $A_\alpha$ is closed then $f$ is continuous.

I have seen a solution to this problem, my question was concerning the method I tried to use to prove this. I was wondering if I could complete it the way I was going:

Say each $\alpha \in J$ is the index set.

If $J$ is finite, then the result follows from a previous part to this question (If $\{A_\alpha\}$ is finite and each $A_\alpha$ is closed, then $f$ is continuous.).

Suppose $J$ were infinite. It follows as $\{A_\alpha\}$ is locally finite, $\bigcap A_\alpha = \varnothing.$ If we let $U_\alpha=X-A_\alpha$, then each $U_\alpha$ is open and it follows that $\{ U_\alpha \}$ is a collection of sets whose union is $X$.

We have a theorem in the text which says that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if $X$ can be written as the union of open sets $V_\alpha$ such that $f\restriction_{V_\alpha}$ is continuous for each $\alpha$.

My question is how could I show that in my case, that each $f\restriction_{U_\alpha}$ is continuous which would mean that $f$ is continuous by the theorem in the text. I've tried picking open sets in $Y$ and trying to look at their pre-image under some $f\restriction_{U_\alpha}$ and show that that must be open in $U_\alpha$. I've not had much luck here as I couldn't find out how to write the pre-image set as the union of open sets. The problem I was having is that I wanted to try to relate $U_\alpha=X-A_\alpha$ to $A_\alpha$ somehow but they are disjoint sets and if I picked an open set in $Y$, its pre-image under the $f\restriction_{A_\alpha}$ is open and then if I tried to translate this to the $U_\alpha$ subspace of $X$ then I could make a closed subset of $U_\alpha$ which isn't helpful as I need something open, I think it isn't helpful at least. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you say that $\bigcap A_α$ is empty, then you are only using that the collection is *point finite*, i.e. each point is only in a finite number of sets. However, the collection is *locally finite*, and this is essential for the proof. If $f$ is continuous on each $A_α$ for a point finite cover, it need not be continuous in $X$.
For an example, take $X=I$ and $A_n=\left[\frac1n, \frac1{n+2}\right]$ for natural $n>0$ and $\ A_\infty=\{0\}$. This gives a point finite closed cover $(A_n)_{n\in\Bbb N^*}$. If you set $f|_{A_n}=1$ and $f(0)=0$, then this map won't be continuous.

To prove your statement for locally finite closed covers, try to show that a set $B\subseteq X$ is closed in $X$ if $B\cap A_α$ is closed in $A_α$ for each $α$.